# why this list means it has 3 or 3 more elements in scala

Tags: list, scala

why this list means it has 3 or 3 more elements in scala

```
x::y::List(xs::ys)::zs
```

can x, y or ys, zs be Empty?
how come it must be a list at least 3 elements according to teacher

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's give this expression some context that makes the types explicit.

```
def foo[A](
  x: List[List[A]],
  y: List[List[A]],
  xs: A,
  ys: List[A],
  zs: List[List[List[A]]]
): List[List[List[A]]] =
  x::y::List(xs::ys)::zs
```

Conventionally, if you have identifiers `x` and `xs`, then `xs` would have a collection type (e.g. `List[A]`) and `x` would be of the collection's element type (e.g. `A`). This isn't the case here, so I think your teacher has made this more difficult than necessary by naming the variables poorly.

Now, for example, let's call `foo` with as few values as possible:

```
> foo(Nil, Nil, 1, Nil, Nil)
res: List[List[List[Int]]] = List(List(), List(), List(List(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's understand the `::` operation, which is right-associative. Given `a :: as`, appends ***element*** `a` to the `List` `as`, emphasis on the ***element***.

If we want to break down this expression, the elements of this list would be...

- Element `x`
- Element `y`
- Element `List(xs::ys)`
- Tail `zs`

As you can see, this expression does't concatenate the lists `xs`, `ys` and `zs`, but instead creates an element which is `List(xs::ys)` and prepends it to `zs`.

This makes sure that the three elements of the list are `x`, `y`, and `List(xs::ys)`. The tail `zs` can either be a list or `Nil` (empty `List`), this expression would have at least 3 elements.

So, the next question is what is the type of this `List`?

Comment: even as you said, why couldn't x, y be empty?

Comment: They are not `List`s themselves, but just elements. Even if they are `null` they occupy and element in the list they're prepended to.

Comment: Well, `x` and `y` probably *are* `List`s, unless the type of the expression is `List[AnyRef]` :)